# Returning a value in a function witch echoes in bash

Tags: bash, function, echo, return-value

I'm trying to create a bash function, but this function must show some messages and return a value.
It's an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

function test() {
        echo "Hello"
        return 0
}

if [ $(test) ]; then
        echo "yes"
else
        echo "no"
fi
```

But I can't capture the returning value, If I do a echo exit.
It's possible?
Regards

Comment: btw.: To avoid surprises, I would not give names to functions that are already assigned as builtin commands. See: `type test`, `help test` and `help help`

Comment: Yes, it's only a sample code, to post it in stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can: `if` branches based on the return status, and assigning the output to a variable does not affect the return status:

```sh
if output=$(testFunc); then
  echo "success: $output"
else
  echo "failure: $output"
fi
```

If you need the return value, you get that from the `$?` variable:

```sh
output=$(foo 0)
rc=$?
if [[ $rc -eq 0 ]]; then        # or `if ((rc == 0))`, an arithmetic comparison
  echo "success: $output $rc"   # $rc will always be 0 here
else
  echo "failure: $output $rc"
fi
```

Comment: This works with a 0 return (ok) or a <>0 return (ko), but how can I catch the recurn value?